# How to retain image quality after uploading it to a server?

Tags: android, bitmapimage

### The code works fine, but the image that is produced looses a good amount of quality. Compression format used is PNG. And also how can I make the image to be saved as .png and not as a .file.

```
public static void writeBitmapToDisk(String filename, Bitmap paramBitmap,
        Context paramContext, Bitmap.CompressFormat paramCompressFormat) {

    Log.e("CL", "paramBitmap.getByteCount()" + paramBitmap.getByteCount());

    String str = constructFileName(filename);
    if (paramBitmap != null) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream localFileOutputStream = paramContext
                    .openFileOutput(str, 0);
            Log.e("CL", "localFileOutputStream" + localFileOutputStream);
            paramBitmap.compress(paramCompressFormat, 100,
                    localFileOutputStream);
            localFileOutputStream.close();
            return;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException localFileNotFoundException) {
            localFileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (IOException localIOException) {
            localIOException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: png is a lossless format, are you sure your paramCompressFormat is correct? It should be Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG

Comment: yeah, its png. The file stored is stored in .file format. Dont know what is it.

Comment: I also tried changing it JPEG to see the difference, but no use, its the same.